# Request for Assistance with JBoss Deployment Issue

Tags: jboss

I hope this message finds you well. I am currently experiencing an issue while trying to deploy a WAR file in JBoss Application Server 7, and I am seeking help from the JBoss community to resolve this matter.

The problem I am facing occurs when I attempt to add the WAR file, and upon clicking "Next," the deployment process does not proceed as expected. I have gone through several troubleshooting steps, such as checking the WAR file, verifying server configuration, and examining error logs, but I have not been able to identify the root cause.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or information that the JBoss community can provide to assist me in resolving this specific deployment issue.

If you have encountered a similar problem or have expertise in JBoss deployments, your assistance would be highly valued.

Please share your suggestions, steps for diagnosing the issue, or any relevant information that may help in finding a solution.

Thank you in advance for your help, and I look forward to your guidance.

[WAR file, and upon clicking "Next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1yJ8.png)

I attempted to deploy a WAR file in JBoss Application Server 7 by using the deployment wizard in the web console. I expected the deployment process to proceed smoothly, with the application being successfully deployed and running. However, when I clicked 'Next' after adding the WAR file, the deployment process did not advance as expected. There was no error message or indication of what went wrong, and the deployment did not complete as it should have. I am seeking assistance to understand the cause of this issue and how to successfully deploy the WAR file

Comment: Do you mean JBoss AS 7 or JBoss EAP 7 ? Which exact vversion ? Did yo try to use the jboss-cli or the deployment scanner to deploy your application ?